# How I can link powerBI and Clockify?

Tags: powerbi, clockify

Can anyone guide me on how to link power and clockfy automatically,I tried doing in many ways

Comment: Please show us your many ways. Tell us what didn't work. Maybe we can help fix those ways. What we can't do is suggest an architecture for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
let
    Query1 = 
    let
        Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.clockify.me/api/workspaces/",
            [Headers=[#"x-api-key"="YOUR-API-KEY"]])),
        #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
        #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id", "name", "hourlyRate", "memberships", "workspaceSettings"}, {"id", "name", "hourlyRate", "memberships", "workspaceSettings"}),
        #"Expanded workspaceSettings" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "workspaceSettings", {"timeRoundingInReports", "onlyAdminsSeeBillableRates", "onlyAdminsCreateProject", "onlyAdminsSeeDashboard", "defaultBillableProjects", "isProjectPublicByDefault", "lockTimeEntries", "round", "projectFavorites", "canSeeTimeSheet", "projectPickerSpecialFilter", "forceProjects", "forceTasks", "forceTags", "forceDescription", "onlyAdminsSeeAllTimeEntries", "onlyAdminsSeePublicProjectsEntries", "trackTimeDownToSecond", "projectGroupingLabel", "adminOnlyPages", "automaticLock", "onlyAdminsCreateTag"}, {"timeRoundingInReports", "onlyAdminsSeeBillableRates", "onlyAdminsCreateProject", "onlyAdminsSeeDashboard", "defaultBillableProjects", "isProjectPublicByDefault", "lockTimeEntries", "round", "projectFavorites", "canSeeTimeSheet", "projectPickerSpecialFilter", "forceProjects", "forceTasks", "forceTags", "forceDescription", "onlyAdminsSeeAllTimeEntries", "onlyAdminsSeePublicProjectsEntries", "trackTimeDownToSecond", "projectGroupingLabel", "adminOnlyPages", "automaticLock", "onlyAdminsCreateTag"}),
        #"Expanded memberships" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded workspaceSettings", "memberships"),
        #"Expanded memberships1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded memberships", "memberships", {"userId", "hourlyRate", "targetId", "membershipType", "membershipStatus"}, {"userId", "hourlyRate.1", "targetId", "membershipType", "membershipStatus"}),
        #"Expanded hourlyRate" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded memberships1", "hourlyRate", {"amount", "currency"}, {"amount", "currency"}),
        #"Expanded round" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded hourlyRate", "round", {"round", "minutes"}, {"round.1", "minutes"}),
        #"Expanded adminOnlyPages" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded round", "adminOnlyPages")
    in
        #"Expanded adminOnlyPages"
in 
    Query1
@Enigmativity
```